# Как сделать чтобы textView не перемешались по экрану на разных устройствах?

Tags: android, android-layout

Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBasText"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAnswer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBasText"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBasText"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Цена питания за следующий месяц:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBasText"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:text="Цена питания за этот месяц:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBasText"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вам посоветую изменить вид вашей разметки. Я имею в виду ваш `relative-layout`. Я бы вам посоветовал его заменить на `linear` или `constraint`. Очень сложно настроить тот вид разметки для каждого экрана. Его я могу использовать внутри `linear`.

### UPDATE

вот сейчас еще одна идейка появилась, я думаю может вам и не критично если будет ваш вид разметки, но можно попробовать закрепить ваш `textView` по отношению к его родителям. Есть теги например `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. То есть вы можете закрепить ваш виджет по отношению к определенным элементам, которые вы указываете по `id`. Вот попалась статья по-моему по вашей тематике: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446229/android-relative-layout-align-parent-right. Там у человека не точно такая же проблема, но он работает с тем же видом шаблонов что и вы.

Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог. Удачи :)

Comment: Это чтобы элементы не перемещались по вертикали?

Comment: там можно настроить так, чтобы элемент зависел от нескольких параметров, не только по вертикали, можно по горизонтали